# Regex Python Adding a char before a random word and the special char :

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find the correct regex lookaround to this type of string:

```py
cat: monkey, ab4 / 1997 / little: cat, 1954/ afgt22 /dog: monkey, 173 / pine-apple: duer, 129378s. / 12
```

The regex I'm trying to set is:

Insert the char '|' before any 'word' followed by ':', being 'word' any type of word with only chars and not numbers.

The issue:

I'm unable to find a way to consider beggining of strings, words containing '-' or words that are preceded of special chars, like '/' and not space, as in this example:

https://regex101.com/r/gX7wY0/5

As you can see, only one of them worked so far, but the '|' char has a space after it, then the word followed by ':'.

What I'm trying to do is:

```py
|cat: monkey, ab4 / 1997 / |little: cat, 1954/ afgt22 /|dog: monkey, 173 / |pine-apple: duer, 129378s. / 12
```

So far only the special char '-' made part of a word before ':'.

Thanks in advance, I'm still learning how to use regex with Python. Any tips are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `r'\b'` to search for word breaks.  For your case you are looking for

- substrings that match: `[A-Za-z\-]+`
- and are surrounded by word breaks: `\b[A-Za-z\-]+\b`
- and are followed by a colon: `\b[A-Za-z\-]+\b:`
- You can capture the word using parenthesis: `\b([A-Za-z\-]+)\b:`
- and recover it in the substitution using `\1`

```
import re

s = 'cat: monkey, ab4 / 1997 / little: cat, 1954/ afgt22 /dog: monkey, 173 / pine-apple: duer, 129378s. / 12'

re.sub(r'(\b[A-Za-z\-]+\b):', r'|\1:', s)
# returns:
'|cat: monkey, ab4 / 1997 / |little: cat, 1954/ afgt22 /|dog: monkey, 173 / |pine-apple: duer, 129378s. / 12'
```

Comment: Thank you @James! This solved the issue and also granted me some more knowledge regarding regex, thank you very much!